# SVT-AV1 Vertical 4k video

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I have a vertical 4k video captured on my phone with the following parameters (ffprobe):

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/smpte170m), 3840x2160, 71980 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.96 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  creation_time   : 2020-04-03T17:17:11.000000Z
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
```

When I try to transcode it to av1 with svt_av1

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v libsvt_av1 -y output.webm
```

I am getting

```
Error instance 1: Source Height must be less than 2160
[libsvt_av1 @ 0x5614a858c400] Error setting encoder parameters: bad parameter (0x80001005)
Segmentation fault
```

How could I encode such videos?

Answer (score 1):

Disable auto rotation:

```
ffmpeg -noautorotate -i video.mp4 -c:v libsvt_av1 -y output.webm
```